# Palindrome Recursion - Infinite loop

Tags: java

When I try running this program, an infinite loop occurs. I can't tell whether the problem is in the main method or in the recursive method.

Here is the recursive method.

```
public class RecursivePalindrome
{
public boolean isPalindrome(String s)
{
    if(s.length() <= 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if(s.charAt(0) == s.charAt(s.length() - 1))
    {
        return isPalindrome(s.substring(1,s.length() - 1 ));
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Here is the main method.

```
public class RecursivePalindromeTester
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a word or phrase. Type Q to quit: ");
    String word = in.next();
    RecursivePalindrome object = new RecursivePalindrome();
    while(!word.equalsIgnoreCase("Q"))
    {
        if(object.isPalindrome(word))
        {
            System.out.println(word + " is a palindrome");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(word + " is not a palindrome");
        }
    }
    System.out.print("Enter another word or phrase. Type Q to quit: ");
    word = in.next();
}
}
```

Comment: @lurker The `endIndex` is exclusive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you are never able to break out of your while loop in your main method.

You should move these two lines into your while loop so the user can enter something else or type "q" to quit:

```
System.out.print("Enter another word or phrase. Type Q to quit: ");
word = in.next();
```

Comment: @TommyLam-Accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You problem lies in this line here:

```
    while(!word.equalsIgnoreCase("Q"))
    {
        if(object.isPalindrome(word))
        {
            System.out.println(word + " is a palindrome");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(word + " is not a palindrome");
        }
    }
    System.out.print("Enter another word or phrase. Type Q to quit: "); //problem
    word = in.next();
```

You are runninging a while loop with nothing to update it

Corrected:

```
    while(!word.equalsIgnoreCase("Q"))
    {
        if(object.isPalindrome(word))
        {
            System.out.println(word + " is a palindrome");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(word + " is not a palindrome");
        }
        System.out.print("Enter another word or phrase. Type Q to quit: ");
        word = in.next();
    }
```

Just as a suggestion, look up Java coding conventions, for example the { is usually left at the end of a line, not on its own, basing your code somewhat on the conventions makes it easier for other people to read

Answer (score 1):

This wile loop is infinite

```
   while(!word.equalsIgnoreCase("Q"))
    {
        if(object.isPalindrome(word))
        {
            System.out.println(word + " is a palindrome");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(word + " is not a palindrome");
        }
    }
```

The while loop keeps looping untill word is set to 'Q', and that happens outside the loop, place this code:

```
    System.out.print("Enter another word or phrase. Type Q to quit: ");
    word = in.next();
```

At the end of your while loop

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: You made the } at the wrong place (You just forgot to include the update of the word variable into the while loop). So just a typo:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a word or phrase. Type Q to quit: ");
        String word = in.next();
        RecursivePalindrom object = new RecursivePalindrom();
        while(!word.equalsIgnoreCase("Q"))
        {
            if(object.isPalindrome(word))
            {
                System.out.println(word + " is a palindrome");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(word + " is not a palindrome");
            }
        // } old postion of the brace
        System.out.print("Enter another word or phrase. Type Q to quit: ");
        word = in.next();
        } // new position of the brace
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you get the next word from the input after the main loop. So the word doesn't get changed and loops forever.